# Fancy groupings with Thinking Sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thinking-sphinx

I have tables boards, users, joins, and roles. The joins table defines the association a user has to a board, as well as the role that user has on that board. I'm trying to either get all of a user's boards at once with a way to differentiate what role a user has on each board, or make three separate calls to get boards that a user is a certain role.

In the board model I have:

```
  define_index do
    indexes :name
    indexes description

    has created_at
    has users(:id), :as => :user
    has joins.role_id, :as => :role

    set_property :enable_star => true
    set_property :min_infix_len => 1
  end
```

and I've been trying queries that are similar to this:

```
Board.search(:with => {:user => some_user.id, :role => some_role.id})
Board.search(:with => {:user => some_user.id}, :group_function => :attr, :group_by => 'role')
```

The problem with the first query is that each board has users that have each possible role, so I get every board the user is associated with, rather than ones for a specific role. As for the second, I'm not sure how I'm getting only the same board returned back to me three times, but that's what's happening.

Thanks in advance for any help/tips.

Answer (score 0):

When you run a grouped query, one matching result *per group* is returned. It sounds like a specific board is being returned for each group, because that board has three roles.

I don't think it's actually possible to do what you want to do in a single query (ie: limit role values to a specific user) - because Sphinx doesn't have any idea of the relationships.

Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: Thanks for the response pat

For the moment I suppose I'll stick with the way I'm getting it to work right now, though it feels a bit messy. I suppose a followup question would be can I create a multiple variable attribute that is perhaps a pair of integers rather than just a list of them, which I was trying to do originally before I read that I couldn't. 

Now that I think about it, since joins has an id, I could have board index the id for join, then do a search_for_ids for the :with in the board search. Perhaps not optimal for getting all roles, but for just one role it's work well enough.